# Javascript body overflow: hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have been experimenting to try to get this to work.

I have 2 checkboxes acting as part of my mobile CSS navigation menu for either side. I have a javascript that prevents more than 1 checkbox to be open at a time. It works.

Now I am trying to add an `overflow:hidden` to the body when either 1 of the checkboxes is checked, obviously if nothing is checked then to remove `overflow:hidden`, but I can't seem to get the first part to work.

I am fairly new to Javascript so any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

```js
function selectOnlyThis(id){
  var myCheckbox = document.getElementsByName("nav-check");
  
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(myCheckbox,function(el){
    if (id != el)
    {
     el.checked = false;
    }
  });

  if (id.checked == false)
  {
   id.checked = false;
  } else
  {
    id.checked = true; 
  } 
  if (id.checked == true)
  {
 $('body').css("overflow", "hidden");
  }
}

// Click, scroll to the top of the document
function topFunction() {
  document.body.scrollTop = 0;
  document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="l-btn">
  <input id="lger" type="checkbox" name="nav-check" onclick="selectOnlyThis(this)"/>
  <label for="lger" onclick="topFunction()"><span></span><span></span</label>
</div>

<div class="r-btn">
  <input id="rger" type="checkbox"  name="nav-check" onclick="selectOnlyThis(this)"/>
  <label for="rger" onclick="topFunction()"><span></span><br/><div>Location</div></label>
</div>
```

Comment: Why do you use `input type="checkbox"` if only one should be possible at a time? ... `input type="radio"` does that by default and no need to involve script.

Comment: Because as stated in my description, it's for a CSS menu which requires the unchecked part of a checkbox which radiobox's do not provide.

Comment: I missed that part. If to in involve script, no need to check if a checkbox is selected or not, simply add/remove a class (one for each box) on a parent and target that with CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do

It takes all the changes made to any `checkbox` and checks if the id is `rger` or `lger` and the checkbox is checked or not, then it changes the `css` with the `jquery` .`css`() method.

```
<div class="r-btn">

<input id="rger" type="checkbox"  name="nav-check" />

<label for="rger" onclick="topFunction()"><span></span><br/><div>Location</div></label>

</div>






  $("input:checkbox").on('change', function () {

                    if (($(this).attr('id')=='rger' || $(this).attr('id')=='lger') && $(this).prop('checked')) {
                        $('body').css("overflow", "hidden");
                    }
                    else

                        $('body').css("overflow", "visible");

            });
```

Refer this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zd45tsye/9/).

Comment: This works, however it only refers to the rger and not lger. I copied the if ($(this.. twice to refer to the lger as well and it worked, however I feel like this can be simplified?

Comment: I tried || right away but I missed the extra brackets! I am somewhat learning. Thank you this is perfect.

Comment: There seems to be a problem with this script, as one of my new members pointed out that checking a checkbox in the signup form caused this function to trigger which is not an Lger or Rger id and still applied the class anyway.

Comment: Also fixed the fiddle.

Comment: Oh wow you're fast. I see what you did there. The attr was needed. It works properly now. My question is would this work if we took out the lger/rger part, and searched for input[name="nav-check"] which both elements are named.

Comment: Put this as another question, the code here will be unreadable.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like your coming from a different programming language? :)
You will love javascript, for example a slim function for your first checkbox.

```
function selectOnlyThis = ({ target }) => {
  const { id, checked } = target;
  id === 'rger' && checked && $('body').css("overflow", "hidden");
}
```

Comment: Looks like it only adds the overflow:hidden to the body if only rger is checked correct? I would like it to be if either of the "nav-check" element names. I tried adding this anyway and it did not work and it conflicts with my owl slider. I will update the original with the other button as well so you understand theres a checkbox for the left menu and checkbox for the right menu

Comment: No one should have to parse though a code to try to understand what it does, explain what you did and how it works. If you need more info, check here: [answer]. Furthermore, an answer is best if you leave out unnecessary comments like _"It looks like your coming from a different programming language?"_.